# how to calculate date difference excluding weekends and holidays in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the number of days between two dates like start and end  but excluding weekends and public holidays. I have table with public holidays date. I saw some example like this

```
select TIMEDIFF(date1,date2) from table 
where date1 not in (select holiday from holiday_table) and
date2 not in (select holiday from holiday_table) and
DAYOFWEEK(date1) not in (1,7) and DAYOFWEEK(date2) not in (1,7)
```

But this will not work because it take only two dates the beginning and the end however anything between it is leaving. Do you have some other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like from your description of the problem that it should be created in an UDF and the logic should be like this:

- Check how many dates fall between the days `select count(1) from holiday_table where holiday between @start and @end`
- Then take the real difference between `@start` and `@end` and subtract the count of holiday_table

Comment: Ok, which means I should use UDF, But the problem is i am not femiler with UDF. Do you have any example in this case.or if it possible can you provide sql query for this. I guess this can be useful for other people as well. Thanks